# How to convert a json into a one line string in Rails and include in a POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to include JSON data in the body of a post request. I will hash the data with a pre-defined key and include it in the header. How can I convert JSON to a one line string with no spaces and include it in the body of a post request as raw data?

Comment: Why don't you want any spaces? How are you going to handle cases like {"key": "value with spaces"}?

Comment: What about url-encoding it?

Comment: @jforberg Actually im trying to convert the php code given by my payment gateway to ruby. It issues a json request like that to their server in order to initiate the payment.

Comment: @eapubs it always helps if you explain what you are trying to do. Well, POST data can include both spaces and newlines so I still don't see why you can't just post the JSON data directly? Who says it can't include spaces?

Comment: @jforberg No one actually that's how the json request came out after feeding the data to the php api they gave me. Im trying to build it from ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove spaces and newlines

```
s = old_s.gsub /[ \n]/, ''
```

I'm not sure why you would need to do this though. It would help if you explained what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Will also remove spaces inside string values.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Rails' `#to_json` method will give you JSON without spaces. So you just need to include it in your request:

```
uri = URI('http://www.example.com/search.cgi')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'myparam' => my_object.to_json)
puts res.body
```

(Modified example from [Net::HTTP documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html))

Any HTTP library (Net::HTTP, HTTParty, etc.) will do all the escaping for you.

Comment: OP needed it to be "a one line string without spaces". With your example, the output retains any spaces that were embedded in quoted string.

Comment: Maybe you are right and my mind-reading abilities failed me. But right now my 6th sense is telling me that he really needed no **insignificant** spaces in JSON, and he didn't mean to strip spaces out of actual values in quotes. His task is to "hash" the string to sign it. I bet the next question will be regarding alphabetical keys sorting in JSON.